# generate time scale by inserting missing week values in list of data frames based on Year value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, zoo

I went through a few articles where a similar question was discussed but I'm facing problem with the complexity of data set that I have.

So I have a list of data frames where each frame has a unique key. Each data frame consists of 2 years of data with units corresponding to each week. There are some week which are missing. Now I want to include those week values and set its corresponding units as zero.

Data frames are as below:

```
ds[[1]]
KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR
A-1  42      2      2019
A-1  24      3      2019
A-1  29      5      2019
A-1  36      6      2019

ds[[2]]
A-2  27      2      2019
A-2  46      3      2019
A-2  44      4      2019

ds[[3]]
B-1  53      2      2019
B-1  31      4      2019
B-1  25      5      2019
B-1  52      6      2019
```

Now I would like to insert those weeks which are missing and set corresponding unit values as zero. So that the output looks like:

```
ds[[1]]
KEY UNITS   WEEK    YEAR
A-1   0      1      2019    
A-1  42      2      2019
A-1  24      3      2019  
A-1   0      4      2019     
A-1  29      5      2019
A-1  36      6      2019

ds[[2]]
A-2   0      1      2019    
A-2  27      2      2019
A-2  46      3      2019
A-2  44      4      2019

ds[[3]]
B-1   0      1      2019    
B-1  53      2      2019
B-1   0      3      2019
B-1  31      4      2019
B-1  25      5      2019
B-1  52      6      2019
```

If the year is not a leap year then the weeks should go till 52, if it is a leap year then the weeks should go to 53. I have gone through similar articles which discussed using zoo object to implement it and then na.fill() to fill zeros. Using zoo object further works well with the next task I need to do with data but i'm not able to implement the proper functionality owing to the complexity of the data set as it is a list of data frames and the inclusion of calculation based on leap year.

My list of data frames is obtained as:

```
ds<-lapply(unique(dataset[, "KEY"]), function(x) {
 tempDf <- dataset[dataset[, "KEY"] %in% x, ]

  return(tempDf)

})
```

If some R genius can help with it, I would be really grateful. 
Thanks

Comment: Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset or multiple datasets in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). It also helps if you include the code you have tried. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: My dataset has many consecutive operations applied o make it a list of data frames. That is the reason I did not include the code snippet. but I'll add it just in case now

Comment: Here's what I would do: 1) create a week-year data frame for all of the week-year combinations you want to hae in your output (2016 weeks 1-53; 2017 weeks 1-52 etc). 2) Collapse your list into a single data frame using dplyr::bind_rows, 3) left_join week-year data frame with your newly collapsed single data frame. 4) replace na's in UNIT column with zeros. 5) use `?split` to  split your data frame back to list of data frames.

Comment: Have you had a look at `tidyr::complete`? or searched for "populating missing dates" ?